# How to make eyes that fit the mesh

Tags: modeling

[image]

I am try to make an anthro fox but the eyes never seem to fit the sockets. Is there any way to model the eyes to fit or do I need to adjust the sockets themselves?

Comment: While you will want to shape your eyelids to be more spherical, you can also use a [lattice deform](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+lattice+deform+eyes) to shape the eyes to fit your mesh.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ruQ5uFrSbg check out the beginning of this tutorial. You just need to insert the eyes and work around them. This explains it really clearly.

Answer (score 3):

**Look at pictures of a real fox!**

You have to model the tear duct.

[image]

Same goes for other eyes, by the way. The Spheres won't fit unless you add a tear duct.